# Shopify Flow condition with date "now" in Liquid not working

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I need to setup Shopify Flow automation that checks "promised by" DATE metafield every day whether it is today or not.

I have following condition [image]

No matter what I do its not working. When I try to add value "2023-03-23" manually it works. Any ideas would help. Thank you!